# how do i use float to convert a value string inside a dictionary and do math with the new values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to learn python with codeacademy, and the assignment was to take two given dictionaries (one is a list of food and the price to buy  + the second is a list of the same foods, but the quantities in stock) and calculate how much revenue i will have if all the foods sell.

At first, i got this error message `"can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'"`.I thought this was weird since the values i was calling are numbers ? o_O but okay, then i tried to convert strings by using the float function (using `float(quan)` and `float(cost)` when i was calculating). but then, i would get this error: `"TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number"`
I also tried to convert by doing `float(prices.value())` but that also gives the same error message.
I think the error is in how i used the float function and not the loop because i tried to print out only cost and quan and the output looked normal.

i would appreciate your help very much.

```
 prices = {
     "banana": 4,
     "apple": 2, 
     "orange": 1.5, 
     "pear": 3, 
 }
 name, cost = prices.keys(), prices.values()    
 stock = {
     "banana": 6,
     "apple": 0,
     "orange": 32,
     "pear": 15
 }
 items, quan = stock.keys(), stock.values()
 for name, cost in prices.iteritems():
    print float(cost) * float(quan)
```

edit: also, is there a function to sum the loop ? because i am supposed to find one single end value if everything sells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to loop over only the keys:

```
for key in prices:
    if key in stock:
        print(prices[key] * stock[key])
```

Though in your case both dictionaries have the same keys, I added a conditional to check that each key in `prices` is also in `stock`.  Then, assuming it is, multiply the dictionary values together.

---

To sum all the values,

```
print(sum(prices[key] * stock[key] for key in prices))
```

If you wish to include the conditional,

```
print(sum(prices[key] * stock[key] for key in prices if key in stock))
```

Or if you'd like it on multiple lines:

```
total = 0

for key in prices:
    total += prices[key] * stock[key]

print(total)
```

Comment: sorry for noob question, but does key refer to the keys of any dictionary that i want to loop over ? or do i have to set key first to be anydictionary.key()?

Comment: @user1476390 My line is `for key in prices` - this iterates over every key value in `prices`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, that makes sense. 
however though, i still have to add up the sum of all the math calculations somehow from the prices[key] * stock[key]. Would you also be willing to help me with that ?

Comment: because using print sum(prices[key] * stock[key]) gives me another float error and i don't know what to do next

Comment: @user1476390 Just added summing to my answer.

Comment: thank you !
do i not have to use a sum function inside the loop because the total is constantly updating each time a food name is being called ?

Comment: @user1476390 Correct.  `sum` takes a list as input and computes the sum of all the values.  If you want to take sum while running through a loop, you need a variable outside the loop to keep adding to.

Answer (score 1):

The `cost` and `quan` are both lists, they can not be passed to `float`. I doubt why you make the solution complex. You can just use:

```
for fruit in prices:
    print prices[fruit] * stock.get(fruit, 0)
```

Or if you want, you can use a dict comprehension to make the result more clear:

```
{fruit: prices[fruit]*stock.get(fruit, 0) for fruit in prices}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `quan` to a list of all the values in the dict. That's not what you want; you're looking for a single value corresponding to the `name` as the key.